# Spring Security for child context - A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a REST API using SpringMVC in an existing (old) application and want to config pre-auth authentication using spring security. However I am getting above error.

Here what I am trying to do is to use a specific context for the REST API and keep the root context to the old application. I want to have security only to my REST API part of the application. (For any URL starting with ../mobile/** )

Please find my Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mobileDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>a.b.c.d.WebConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mobileDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mobile/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.mobileDispatcher</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/mobile/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Please find my security config class

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource( {"classpath:/spring-security.xml" })
public class SecurityConfig {}
```

My spring-security.xml

```
<sec:http auto-config='true'>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/mobile/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</sec:http>
<beans:bean id="inMemoryAuthenticationUserDetailsService"
            class="a.b.c.d.InMemoryAuthenticationUserDetailsService"/>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="inMemoryAuthenticationUserDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper"
            class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
    <beans:property name="attributePrefix" value=""/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="webXmlMappableAttributesRetriever"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever"/>

<beans:bean id="j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource">
    <beans:property name="mappableRolesRetriever" ref="webXmlMappableAttributesRetriever"/>
    <beans:property name="userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper" ref="simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="appControlAuthenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationDetailsSource"
                    ref="j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="appControlAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

What could be the reason for this issue ? After going through similar questions in stack overflow it feels like I have to put the security context to the root context but I don't want to touch the root context as it has been used by the existing application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the above configuration, The issue was accidentally in another Config file I have imported spring-security.xml. So the spring-security.xml has been imported twice. Once I remove that it all worked perfectly.